# add a special symbol to character class alnum

Tags: regex, shell, awk, special-characters

Can i add something to a character class ?

like we know

```
              [:alnum:]
```

contains all alpha numeric characters !!

So i want to add a special symbol (.) dot to the class !!
How can we do it?

I tried this,

```
       class='\.*[:alnum:]'
       newclass="[$class]"
```

storing a class alnum and dot into a variable string newclass and after that using $newclass in awk but no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include any character like:

```
[.[:alnum:]]
```

Testing this in a BASH regex:

```
[[ 'abc.123' =~ ^[.[:alnum:]]+$ ]] && echo "ok" || echo "no"
ok

[[ 'abc.123' =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+$ ]] && echo "ok" || echo "no"
no
```

Comment: and how can i negate [.[:alnum:]]

Comment: awk 'length()<3 || length()>15 || /^[.[:alnum:]]+$/' temp.csv

Comment: For negation you can use: `[^.[:alnum:]]` Also I cannot test your awk command since you've not provided sample data from `temp.csv`

Comment: i wanna print all lines whose lengths  less than 3 or greater than 15 and who dont have a dot or are not alphanumeric!!

Answer (score 2):

`Can i add something to a character class ?` - no, you can't.

Having said that, character classes (e.g. `[:alnum:]`) are often used within bracket expressions (e.g. `[[:alnum:]]`) and you **can** have multiple character classes and/or character lists and/or character ranges within a bracket expression, e.g.:

```
[[:alnum:].]
```

or:

```
[[:alnum:][:space:][:cntrl:]#-&@]
```

When using regexps it's very important to understand the terminology and differences between:

```
bracket expressions
character classes
character lists
character ranges
```

Comment: You can also stress the fact that the terminology refers to POSIX regex.

Comment: I'm not familiar with different terminology for non-POSIX regex - could you elaborate?

Comment: There is a kind of a terminological conflict with [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class), where a *character class* (in NFA regexps) = *bracket expression* (in POSIX regexps).

Comment: Yeah I saw that site once before used different terminology and found it extremely confusing that they used the term "character class" to mean both a bracket expression and a character class. I assumed it was just one more site written by people who didn't really know what they were talking about.

Comment: Actually, I think the consensus is to use *POSIX character class* to denote things like `[:alpha:]` and a *character class* in the meaning of a *bracket expression*. That is, in the non-POSIX regex world.

Comment: They say that in some places but not all. They also talk about `\d` meaning `[0-9]` etc as if that were universal (its not) and then they say things like `Shorthand character classes can be used both inside and outside the square brackets. \s\d matches a whitespace character followed by a digit. [\s\d]` when that's simply not true in general and that's a clear case where they use the term `character class` to mean what elsewhere they refer to as `POSIX character class` and they're using `inside the square brackets` to mean what they previously meant by `character class`, etc. IMHO it's a mess.

Comment: What you quoted is perfectly correct in context.  In the world of Perl-derivative regexes, "character class" means roughly what "bracket expression" does in POSIX-standard regexes.  I agree it's a mess, but it's a mess that's here to stay.

Comment: That's perl-derived? Now I understand :-). Anyway, just stick with POSIX terminology don't buy into the wackiness.